# dart:ui:1: Error: Not found: dart:ui. flutter/dart:

Tags: dart, flutter

When I start a debugging session (pressing F5) I receive the following messages:

```
dart:ui:1: Error: Not found: dart:ui.
Exited (sigterm)
```

There is no indication as to where the problem occurred. Output from **flutter doctor -v** is:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.8.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 0.8.2 at C:\Downloads\flutter\flutter_windows_v0.5.1-beta\flutter
    • Framework revision 5ab9e70727 (2 weeks ago), 2018-09-07 12:33:05 -0700
    • Engine revision 58a1894a1c
    • Dart version 2.1.0-dev.3.1.flutter-760a9690c2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\gggustafson\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-27, build-tools 27.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 26.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.25.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 2.18.0

[√] Connected devices (1 available)
    • SM G925V • 06157df60c7a8e20 • android-arm64 • Android 7.0 (API 24)

• No issues found!
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: It seems your IDE infer your application as a simple dart project, not a flutter one.

Comment: What file are you using as entry-point? You see it if you click the configuration dropdown on the left side of the run button in the toolbar and click `Edit Configurations ...`

Comment: In the Debug, next to the Start Debugging icon, there is a drop-down from which can be selected either "No Configurations" or "Add Configuration...". Currently the selected configuration is "No Configurations".

Comment: Sorry, missed the first part of your question. I am working on a conversion of the Vanilla project from GitHub. I am trying to: combine all dart files into a minimum number of directories, then remove all "unnecessary" files (localization, etc.) and reduce Vanilla to an example of application state sharing, and finally using the revised Vanilla as an example, write my own app. The entry point is main() in main.dart. Have I answered your question?

Comment: Did you enable Flutter support for the project. Check that the Dart SDK from Flutter is selected in Dart settings instead of a standalone Dart SDK

Comment: In the Dart Configuration setting, I find

In the default settings:

    "dart.checkForSdkUpdates": true,
    "dart.debugSdkLibraries": false,
    "dart.flutterSdkPath": "",
    "dart.flutterSdkPaths": [],
    "dart.sdkPath": "",
    "dart.sdkPaths": [],

In the user settings:

    "dart.sdkPath": "",

Thoughts?

Comment: In my case, Android Studio identfied all but one of my test classes as Flutter tests. In order to correct it, I had to 'edit configuration', DELETE the incorrectly associated test and enter it again as a Flutter test. Editing the existing entry did not work.

Comment: maybe your FlutterSDK is not defines, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48650831/dart-sdk-is-not-configured

Answer (score 158):

When running the app, you will find `2 main.dart`
Choose the one with the flutter icon beside it
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. The problem has disappeared. I don't know why but I did flutter new project. I think that was the problem.

Comment: I feel so silly after knowing this was the problem

Answer (score 19):

If you are using **VS Code** as your IDE then choose **Start Debugging** instead of *Run Code* and it will work.

[image: Screenshot here]

Answer (score 17):

**If you are running flutter project.**

In edit configuration, run it as flutter project,which has a flutter icon besides it.

**If you are testing a dart file**

Check your denpendency tree. Delete all flutter related lib like widgets/material/cupertino.

**Simple explaination**

In short, you are running a file as dart file, but you have imported flutter dependencies like widgets/material at the same time. Either run it as flutter ,or get rid of flutter dependency and run pure dart.

Answer (score 7):

Magically if you add:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
```

at the top of that file you want to Run or Debug, and delete the existing configuration, it will run as flutter instead of dart.

Why? Idea/Android Studio scans the file that you're asking to Run or Debug for flutter imports and uses that to decide whether the initial run configuration should be a dart or flutter one. If you import any flutter packages, you get a flutter run configuration.

Confusingly, it does this only the first time you Run/Debug that file, and remembers the run configuration.
If your run configuration was created as the wrong kind (Dart instead of Flutter), you'll need to go into the "Edit Configurations" menu to delete it, than are to Run/Debug that file again.

Its very confusing behavior, particularly since your imports are insufficient to know whether the file should be run as Flutter or plain old Dart -- your file's import may import another file that imports a flutter library. It may be detected as Dart, when Flutter it the right configuration.

They should have just added "Run Dart", "Run Flutter".

Comment: hm? where file do you mean?

Comment: At the top of the file that you are trying to run or debug.
Idea/Android Studio scans the for for flutter imports and uses that to decide whether the initial run configuration should be a dart or flutter one. If you import any flutter packages, you get a flutter run configuration.

Answer (score 1):

While running choose the one with the flutter icon and it should help.

Answer (score 1):

Has the same problem for almost a week. My solution was to debug (Start Debug) and not Run (Run Code).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VSCode, change your launch.json's cwd. For me, I am working on a plugin, and I have VScode opened at the root of the plugin. And if you're trying to run `example/lib` make sure you don't add `/lib.

```
...
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "example",
        "cwd": "example",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "dart"
    },
]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you're running a Flutter app as a Dart app.  So, select the run config with the Flutter icon.

You could run the app from the command line

```
flutter run lib/main_development.dart
```

to simulate the error try:

```
dart run lib/main_development.dart
```

If you don't have a run configuration with a flutter icon.

1. Select the "Edit Configurations" in Intellij Idea (or similar in other IDEs)
   [image]
2. Click the plus icon, scroll down and select flutter and enter the location to your main file entry point (main.dart).

If you don't see the flutter item in your list of configurations.  Install the Flutter plugin or reinstall it (pay attention for any error messages after reinstall).

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal and run `flutter doctor`, it worked for me.

> but still can't run project using `run` button

Answer (score -5):

Import this library

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
```