# How to solved 'dart:ui' error when going to run flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter

[image]Below error occurs when I try to run my first flutter app.

```html
file:///Volumes/Data/FlutterSDk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/action_sheet.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show ImageFilter;
       ^
 file:///Volumes/Data/FlutterSDk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/bottom_tab_bar.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show ImageFilter;
       ^
file:///Volumes/Data/FlutterSDk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/colors.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show Color;
       ^
file:///Volumes/Data/FlutterSDk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/dialog.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show ImageFilter;
       ^
 file:///Volumes/Data/FlutterSDk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/nav_bar.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show ImageFilter;
       ^
 file:///Volumes/Data/FlutterSDk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/slider.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
 file:///Volumes/Data/FlutterSDk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/cupertino/switch.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
 file:///Volumes/Data/FlutterSDk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:9:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' as ui show Paint, Path, Canvas;
       ^   file:///Volumes/Data/FlutterSDk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:10:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^  file:///Volumes/Data/FlutterSDk/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/arc.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^

Process finished with exit code 254
```

I have tried many ways to solve this issue but still, this issue is coming.

Comment: are you sure you installed dart plugin correctly? Can you share your `flutter doctor -v` result?

Comment: yes because when I fire "flutter Doctor" its display no error.

Comment: I mean all the errors works fine on my PC. Can you share your `flutter doctor -v` result? It doesn't have to show an error, seeing your system information is also useful.With the only code above, no one can help.

Comment: Okay, I have modified my question. Check screenshot

Comment: When run the app, you will find 2 main.dart Choose the one with the flutter icon beside it enter image. Check this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAGBx.png

Comment: Thanks. Now it's working.

Comment: Okay I will add this as an answer then. Can you accept it?

Comment: Yes sure I will

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you run the app, you will see 2 `main.dart` entry. Please pick the one with Flutter icon. I get it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52813358/1744873).

[image]

Answer (score 39):

You are getting those errors because your IDE is executing `main.dart` as a simple dart application and not as a Flutter application.

As answered by salihguler, if you are using Android SDK then choose the `main.dart` file with **Flutter Icon** beside it and not the one with **Dart Icon** and the project should work just fine.

[image: Android SDK Option Image]

If you are using VS Code then instead of hitting **Run** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) go to **Debug** -> **Start Debugging** option or simply press <kbd>F5</kbd> and errors will be gone.

[image: Visual Code Option Image]

Answer (score 2):

For me the culprit was a transitive dependency on Flutter. I was running a dart file that imported a functional class that I copied from another project. This class did not apparently depend on Flutter but it was importing a package for logging and that package was depending on Flutter.

When running a dart executable, make sure you do not use any Flutter specific classes anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VSCode, you might need to open Folder more closely to your `main.dart`.

Bad Folder Structure Example on the left side:

- Backend
- Frontend

  - FlutterApp
  - lib

    - main.dart

Working:

- FlutterApp

  - lib

    - main.dart

Finally, I saved workplace as second one, and changed to first one, all works! Here is the related [issue discussion](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1549).

Answer (score 0):

had the same error message when working on command line based dart files,  i had accidentally

**imported cupertino**   packages on some dart files.
 try using material design only on your project and remove the cupertino package import on your files
P.S i had no issue working on the real flutter app. and i use android studio

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, but pressing "F5 running on debug mode" worked for me. Additionally I don't need to install XCode and Android Studio as well, which was described as a problem in flutter doctor command.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on VS code and are using extensions to run the code, don't. You should disable them and use the flutter extension it self to launch the main.dart.

Answer (score 0):

dude this is a bit silly and ridiculous but are you sure you have the code void main(){} inside your main.dart file?

Comment: I have asked before 7 months when I was new in a flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to debug the program, if you're usign vscode, press <kbd>control/command</kbd>  + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> and debug the project, afetr that is solved