# Flutter Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform, using VSCode

Tags: flutter, dart

I have Dart library error (the error in the title), when trying to run a Flutter file on VSCode, i tried everything in the old posts about the same problem, yet it still persists.

I can run flutter manually, using `flutter run`, but then hot reload and hot restart don't work. I need to retry debugging (and always get the same error), then again run flutter manually to see the changes i've made.

I tried `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`, yet it doesn't work. Still  Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform error persists.

I sent my code to my friend and she can debug and run it without `flutter run`.

Sorry if my formatting is bad, new here.

Comment: I thing this post maybe help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54072544/how-to-solved-dartui-error-when-going-to-run-flutter-app

Answer (score 0):

You'll get an error stating that `dart:ui` isn't available when trying to run a project with a Flutter dependency with the standalone Dart runtime (i.e., `dart run` vs `flutter run`) as only Flutter provides the `dart:ui` library.

It sounds like there might be something misconfigured in your VSCode launch options.

Comment: Thank you, but i couldn't understand what i might have misconfigured while installing VSCode/Flutter, have you got any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, without being able to dig through your configuration, I don't think I can give much more advice :-(