# Error while running Dart Sample Project in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: dart, flutter

Can anyone help me understand where is the issue? I'm unable to get the desired output for the below code?
Please check the below ***code*** and ***Log***

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

/Users/chandramoulireddyporeddy/Documents/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart --enable-asserts --enable-vm-service:61567 /Users/chandramoulireddyporeddy/Documents/Workspace/flutter_app1/lib/main.dart
Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:61567/

lib/main.dart:1: Warning: Interpreting this as package URI, 'package:flutter_app1/main.dart'.
lib/main.dart:3:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui';
       ^
file:///Users/chandramoulireddyporeddy/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:9:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' as ui show Paint, Path, Canvas;
       ^
file:///Users/chandramoulireddyporeddy/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:10:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
file:///Users/chandramoulireddyporeddy/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/arc.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
file:///Users/chandramoulireddyporeddy/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/colors.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show Color;
       ^
file:///Users/chandramoulireddyporeddy/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dialog.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui';
       ^
file:///Users/chandramoulireddyporeddy/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_border.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
file:///Users/chandramoulireddyporeddy/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_decorator.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
file:///Users/chandramoulireddyporeddy/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/mergeable_material.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
file:///Users/chandramoulireddyporeddy/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/shadows.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
import 'dart:ui' show Color, Offset;
       ^

Process finished with exit code 254

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of
[dart:ui:1: Error: Not found: dart:ui. flutter/dart:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52483773/dartui1-error-not-found-dartui-flutter-dart)

There should be two run configurations when you run the app, run the one with the Flutter icon

Comment: I see only one run configurations.

Comment: Mind appending the output of flutter doctor to your question?

Comment: I restarted the IDE, issue fixed automatically.

Comment: at the top of Android Studio, there is a drop-down menu with targets. It probably says "main.dart".
Inside the box, left of the "main.dart", there is a blue symbol. Either it is an "[ (F) main.dart ]" (the Flutter logo) or it is a Dart-arrow fin logo "[ (X) main.dart ]". It should be the "F" version to build properly, so select that.

Answer (score 0):

This really helped thanks! My 2 cents to mark up for readability.

**Error:**

> packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_navigation_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'

followed many import statement errors such as `import 'dart:ui' as ui show Paint, Path, Canvas;` `import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble`;

**Solution:**
*In Android Studio, in **targets drop-down** next to devices drop-down, please ensure to **choose Flutter main.dart**, NOT Dart main.dart. One can distinguish this with the corresponding logo.*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).