# Test framework quit unexpectedly - Dart project on MAC

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, intellij-idea, dart, flutter

I'm trying to develop a Dart package for my Flutter project.
It only consists of Dart (so no Flutter) code.

When trying to run my unit tests with Android Studio or IntelliJ I get the following error:
`Test framework quit unexpectedly`
In the output window I get the following messages:

```
Testing started at 21:38 ...
/Users/<user>/development/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/pub run test -r json /Users/<user>/Projects/personal/<project dir>/<project>
Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:57505/

Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/Users/<user>/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/test-1.5.3".

Process finished with exit code 66
```

The whole `.pub-cache` directory doesn't even exists...

How do I get the testing to work?

Comment: Getting this issue too.

Answer (score 3):

I had the error messages: 
"Test framework quit unexpectedly" "The flutter SDK is not available"

The problem was that I configure the unit tests as Dart tests.

Solution in  InteliJ:
`Run > Edit Configurations... > + symbol on the top left > Flutter Test` (to use the Flutter template instead of the Dart template)

`Test scope: All in Directory` and choose `your_project/lib` folder. This will search for all files named as *_test.dart

This thread helped figuring this out: [dart:ui:1: Error: Not found: dart:ui. flutter/dart:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52483773/dartui1-error-not-found-dartui-flutter-dart)

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded the separate Dart SDK en configured Android Studio and IntelliJ to use it instead of the one that ships with Flutter.

Now the tests are working again.