# How to solve 'dart:ui' problem while running flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Here is the result of flutter doctor -v command - 1:

[image]

Another image- 2:

[image]

You can see the error in output section as it says to import 'dart:ui' as ui. I have tried it but still it's not working.:

[image]

I tried to add all the instructions shown in output section. And still I face the same problem. I'm stuck in this. So, I am humbly requesting to find the solution of this problem which can lead me to go further. Thanks

Comment: Are you able to create and run a small project with same structure? becuase it basically seems folder or running steps exacpetion. [Check this link](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/3834)  its already explained in detail

Answer (score 0):

My guess is youre trying to run the project as `dart` file, not `Flutter`. You can check out this answer for [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52483773/dartui1-error-not-found-dartui-flutter-dart)