# Can I install and configure developer tools (Xcode, Flutter, Android Studio) on an external drive?

Tags: xcode, android-studio, flutter, installation

I bought an external SSD because I got a lot of trouble with mac storage capacity (128GB).
So can I install flutter, android studio, and Xcode on an external SSD, for mac?

**EDIT:**
There are two users on my mac, can both use Xcode, android studio and flutter if I install them on the SSD?

Comment: I have updated the question to contain what is actually asked for, not just the Flutter part. Answering it now.

Comment: EDIT: If nobody has answered it when I get home from work, I'll answer it 

Comment: Took a bit longer than expected. Realized that you ask for a multi-user setup. Homebrew was never designed to work as a multi-user environment, that is the only problem with this setup. But I've done this once myself, there are ways to get around this without too much witchcraft. I only know one way that has worked for me over time though. Just have to do some digging and write a "downvote-proof" answer.  Stay tuned. Stay healthy. Peace out.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for spending your time for the community.

Comment: Yeah, I'm deep down in a hole somewhere now, trying to dig my way out. I was smart enough to jump in head-first and delete my Homebrew install to figure out the best way to do it "multi-user" friendly, against most odds, as the answer on the Homebrew forum is basically "Doesn't work". But, I don't accept that answer yet. Has to be a way that actually works. I'm close (I think).

Comment: @cseder have found something out?

Comment: Somehow my last comment has either been deleted or not registered properly. Answer: yes, and no. The problem is the multiple users part. I have a working setup myself, where everything that takes lots of space has been configured to run from my external ssd. But Homebrew is not easy to get to work with  more than one user. I've tried different ways found on the internet, but something always breaks in regards to libraries, permissions, the cooperation between Flutter and Xcode build + Cocoapods or the Homebrew <-> Xcode Developer Tools when I try to use a user other than the primary user...

Comment: I was thinking about trying to use MacPorts instead of Homebrew, but have not gotten around to trying that as of yet. Sorry for giving up, I really hate giving up, but after 6 hours ++ trying to solve it, at least I tried...  Last time I didn't have Flutter to consider, but adding this  and Xcodebuild to the mix complicates the issue further.

Comment: Thank you so much for spending so much time! Have you at least a solution to install all those things and use just for one user?

Comment: Yes, sure. As I said, I've done that for quite a while now. I use VS Codium primarily, but I can easily afford having Android Studio and a bunch of emulators when everything is on the external drive. Tried building both Android and iOS apps using Android Studio and it works fine  I'll post an answer as soon as I have some spare time on my plate. Maybe you could have 3 users and use one as a shared developer account.