# Can I use flutter with my Xcode installed in External Harddrive?

Tags: xcode, macos, flutter

I'm currently a student and on our Mobile Computing subject we are asked to install Flutter. I am using a MacBook Pro early 2015 and when I run flutter doctor it says that I need to install Xcode, however, my IDE of choice is VSCode.

My question is, would it be possible to use flutter in an Xcode installed in an external hard drive? This is because Xcode is eating up most of my free space. If it is possible, what are the pros and con of it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I install Xcode on an external hard drive along with the iPhone Simulator.app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59159232/can-i-install-xcode-on-an-external-hard-drive-along-with-the-iphone-simulator-ap)

Comment: See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/vs-code

Answer (score 0):

Xcode does not have to be on the *internal* drive, but it must be in the Applications directory of the *startup* drive.

Comment: Thanks! How can I do that?

Comment: Obviously you would need a startup drive that is not the internal drive. In my view, not worth the trouble. Instead you should wonder what’s taking up all the space on the internal drive.