# Background color won't change xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, background, solid-state-drive

I just opened up a new default swift project, and no matter what I do, this background color will not change. As you can see, I have it set to the system yellow color but it's still on the default black color it comes with. The internal error warning keeps coming up as you can see in the photo below, and even if I clear the derived data it's still there so it may have something to do with that. It may also be important to mention that I'm running xcode off of an external ssd which I figured out how to do using [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59159232/can-i-install-xcode-on-an-external-hard-drive-along-with-the-iphone-simulator-ap) instructions. It does say that I may run into issues as the answer is for older versions of xcode, so that could be something, I'm not sure. Thanks in advance!

[I don't have 10 reputation yet so here's the photo link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9SqX.jpg)

Comment: "An internal error occurred." Seems like Xcode is glitching out - happens every so often. Quit and relaunch and it should work as expected.