# How can I run an independent dart file in Visual Studio Code when my app is already running?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I have an already running Flutter project in Visual Studio Code,
but I want to run a separate Dart file in the same project without terminate my running project.

When i tried to run this file, the running project stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open your terminal and execute your dart file like

`$ dart ./file.dart`

> To open the terminal, use any of this options:
>
> - Use the ⌃` keyboard shortcut with the backtick character.
> - Use the View > Terminal menu command.
> - From the Command Palette (⇧⌘P), use the View: Toggle Integrated Terminal command.
>     https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Comment: i tried this in terminal but this was the result
$' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: The symbol $ is not meant to be used, it was to indicate is a command. Do `dart ./file.dart`

Comment: i found this 
'dart' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: You have to add the dart sdk to your path variable as you probably did with Flutter. Hope this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49227850/8096916