# flutter flutter-web-sdk-windows-x64 failed download

Tags: flutter, dart

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.22.0-12.4.pre, on Microsoft Windows [VersiÃ³n 10.0.17763.1], locale es-US)
• Flutter version 1.22.0-12.4.pre at C:\flutter
• Framework revision f30b7f4db9 (4 weeks ago), 2020-10-08 10:06:30 -0700
• Engine revision 75bef9f6c8
• Dart version 2.10.1
```

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\Darknight\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
X Flutter requires Android SDK 29 and the Android BuildTools 28.0.3
To update the Android SDK visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin version 48.1.2
• Dart plugin version 193.7547
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.50.1)
• VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.16.0

[√] Proxy Configuration
• HTTP_PROXY is set
• NO_PROXY is localhost://127.0.0.1
• NO_PROXY contains 127.0.0.1
• NO_PROXY contains localhost

[√] Connected device (2 available)
• Web Server (web) • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
• Chrome (web)     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 86.0.4240.183

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

flutter run -v -d chrome
[ +141 ms] Downloading Web SDK... (completed in 911.0s)
[   +4 ms] Downloading Web SDK...

Failed to download https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/flutter/75bef9f6c8ac2ed4e1e04cdfcd88b177d9f1850d/flutter-web-sdk-windows-x64.zip. Ensure you have network connectivity and then
try again.

I have downloaded in my browser this link for flutter-web-sdk-windows-x64.zip but I don't know where to put it

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your flutter installation as mentioned: Flutter requires Android SDK 29 and the Android BuildTools 28.0.3 To update the Android SDK visit flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.

[This post might be of help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48650831/dart-sdk-is-not-configured)

Answer (score 0):

Put the file in `[flutter sdk]/bin/cache/downloads/**`.
There will be nested empty folders in this path, enter the innermost folder.
This folder will be created if you fail to download, and the files in your Downloads path will be automatically deleted when you run the command again after the copy operation.
The `flutter_web_sdk` directory is generated in the `bin/cache/` directory.

chinese use unicode decoding : https://www.bejson.com/convert/unicode_chinese/

\u5c06\u4e0b\u8f7d\u597d\u7684\u6587\u4ef6\u653e\u5165 %60flutter sdk%60 \u5b89\u88c5\u76ee\u5f55\u4e2d\u7684 %60bin/cache/downloads/..%60 \uff0c\u5176\u4e2d\u7684\u6587\u4ef6\u5939\u4f1a\u5728\u4f60\u4e0b\u8f7d\u5931\u8d25\u7684\u65f6\u5019\u81ea\u52a8\u521b\u5efa\u597d\uff0c\u53ea\u9700\u8981\u590d\u5236\u5230\u6700\u5185\u5c42\u7684\u7a7a\u6587\u4ef6\u5939\u4e2d\u5373\u53ef\u3002\u4e4b\u540e\u518d\u6b21\u8fd0\u884c\u547d\u4ee4\uff0c\u590d\u5236\u7684\u6587\u4ef6\u5c06\u4f1a\u81ea\u52a8\u5220\u9664\uff0c\u5e76\u5728 %60bin/cache%60 \u76ee\u5f55\u4e2d\u751f\u6210\u4e00\u4e2a %60flutter_web_sdk%60 \u6587\u4ef6\u5939\u3002

Comment: I doubt that this is the right way to get things fixed. I'd rather advise the poster to strictly follow the setup-instructions mentioned: Flutter requires Android SDK 29 and the Android BuildTools 28.0.3 To update the Android SDK visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.