# Flutter dart showing errors

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, sdk

I've installed flutter on Android studio whenever I import a new project on Android studio it shows "Dart not configured Download Dart SDK or Open Dart settings"

[image: Showing this]

The code was fine till now.

When I open the dart settings & select flutter path & hit on apply all the code starts showing errors.

[image: The whole code is full of errors]

Idk what to do tried with every project only when making a new flutter project is working fine. Flutter version is 2.8.1
Dart version is 2.15.1
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4

Comment: What errors? You forgot to include them. Please copy and paste some representative examples, as text. Anyway: have you perhaps tried configuring Dart SDK as it suggests?

Comment: you need to download sdk top of the right corner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you `installed the Dart properly`, as Android Studio indicates it in your first Screenshot. Also see [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install).
If this is your case make sure that you `choose the correct SDK Location`, which you selected during installation. Also make sure, that the `Flutter SDK Path` is correctly set up under `File->Settings->Language & Framework->Flutter.`

If this does not help check out suggested solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48650831/15117201).

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the flutter sdk with terminal or by downloading the directory? If it's the later, first make sure to select the right dart sdk path in the settings. It's in `your_flutter_directory/bin/cache/dart-sdk` and then flutter sdk path. After this try running `flutter pub get` to see if it works.