Message "No Connected Devices Found" in 'Android Studio'
First of all, before I start writing, please understand that I am not good at English because I am Korean.
I am trying to create an application with Flutter.
So I installed Android Studio.
Here is the output.
No Connected Devices Found
my Output Image
This is the output of flutter doctor
[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4291], locale ko-KR)
    ! Warning: `flutter` on your path resolves to C:\Users\User\flutter, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK
      checkout at C:\flutter. Consider adding C:\flutter\bin to the front of your path.
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.81.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources

Please help me!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48650831/dart-sdk-is-not-configured?rq=2
Please refer to it and do the configuration. Once You've done the settings everything , please restart android studio.
As per the image you've shared, there is the dart support is not enabled message
Enable it, The issue will be resolved

Are you sure you have created an emulator/simulator?
